# how to change the color of the cursor in flutter search delegate?

Tags: flutter, dart, search

I have implemented flutter search delegate feature in flutter app.Now I want to change the color of the cursor as it is white color and background of the search bar is also white. I need to highlight of cursor color to black.

I tried the appbarTheme inside the searchDelegate class but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

> Add this in MaterialApp (it will change cursor color for all screens)

```
theme: ThemeData(
        textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
          cursorColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
```